# Lubuntu folder created?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, lubuntu

Groovy Gorilla
Linux zika 5.8.0-48-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 19 14:25:20 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Last month I did some boot/grub/bios/UEFI settings, trying to get confused a bit more than I am, however soon after I found out a new 'lubuntu' directory was created in my /home. Can anybody relate this to something? I do not want to just rm it and not knowing why and how was getting there. There is no user 'lubuntu' created.

Thanks!

```
root@zika:/home/lubuntu/.rpmdb# ls -la
total 532
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Mar 23 11:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Mar 23 11:30 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Basenames
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Conflictname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 311295 Mar 23 11:35 __db.001
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  81919 Mar 23 11:35 __db.002
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 266239 Mar 23 11:35 __db.003
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      0 Mar 23 11:30 .dbenv.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Dirnames
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Enhancename
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Filetriggername
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Group
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Installtid
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Name
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Obsoletename
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  12288 Mar 23 11:30 Packages
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Providename
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Recommendname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Requirename
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Sha1header
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Sigmd5
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Suggestname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Supplementname
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Transfiletriggername
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   8192 Mar 23 11:30 Triggername
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the RPM database. Did you install any RPMs recently?

Background: You can install RPM as a secondary package manager on Ubuntu, and then you can install RPM packages as well as the usual DEB packages.

Check with `rpm -qa` if (a) RPM is installed and (b) what RPMs you have installed.

Comment: Thanks! I realized that it was a rpmdb I had the RPM PM installed but I do not install any rpms last month. Why in /home? I check rpm -qa and nothing returned. Where else should I check? I found some lubuntu-grub-theme_20.10.3_all.deb (I installed) also converted rpm by alien: refind and avast4.